# git push -u origin master no answer

Tags: git, github, repository, git-push

I'm tryint to push two files from my local machine to gihub just for testing, I have an empty repository called test on github, and a local repository test on my machine. But gets no answer after `git push -u origin master` here's what i did in the command window:

```
C:\Users\TJIA\Documents\GitHub\test [master]> git remote add origin https://gith
ub.com/Svampyr/test.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
C:\Users\TJIA\Documents\GitHub\test [master]> git remote rm origin
C:\Users\TJIA\Documents\GitHub\test [master]> git remote add origin https://gith
ub.com/Svampyr/test.git
C:\Users\TJIA\Documents\GitHub\test [master]> git push -u origin master
```

I'm new to github, anyone can correct me, thanks!

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the username in your remote path? I've always seen it as `https://username@github.com/username/project.git`

Comment: No, this is not needed anymore..

Answer (score 1):

Create a new local folder and try to do this: Does this work for you?
You can add your files to this new folder and try with them;)

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/Svampyr/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

Maybe there is *no* commit in your repository?
If you don't know, type "git log" and check if there is one or not.

Comment: Still not getting any answer, maybe it's restricted at my company just suspecting. There is a commit `C:\Users\TJIA\Documents\GitHub\tonyt [master]> git log
commit b892672f376f3063f7dc68034c4ef8e1d293148d
Author: Tony Jiang <tony_jiang_1_1@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 9 09:48:51 2012 +0200

    first commit`

Answer (score 0):

To see what is happening, try running:

```
GIT_TRACE=2 git push -u origin master
```

Also have you tried pushing to the SSH url instead of the https url?

Comment: `The term 'GIT_TRACE=2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, scr
ipt file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
 included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:12
+ GIT_TRACE=2 <<<<  git push -u origin master
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (GIT_TRACE=2:String) [], Command
   NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: Right, Windows, forgot about that. You just need to set the environment variable, maybe `set GIT_TRACE=2` was the right syntax for Windows? :)